# jquery animation triggers the first time but not after changing classes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The following animation works exactly as I need it to the first time that the function is called, but after the function changes the classes only the opacity animation works when you call the function and the slide left does not even try to execute. I'm a noob to Jquery so I'm not sure what is causing that one animation not to work while the other one works fine... Any tips are greatly appreciated. The example can be found at www.digitalbrent.com/lab - click on populate, then click on decrease.

```
function slider_minus(){

    $('.left_slot').animate({
        left: '50px'        //only works on first function call
    },300);

    $('.middle_slot').animate({
        left: '50px'        //only works on first function call
    },300, function(){
         $('.middle_slot').attr('class','right_slot')
         $('.left_slot').attr('class','middle_slot')
    });

    $('.right_slot').animate({
        opacity: 0,         //works correctly every time
        left: '50px'        //only works on first function call
    },300);
}
```

Comment: Probably would helpful if we had some html or an example at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: check it out... www.digitalbrent.com/lab - click on populate, then click on decrease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting `left:50px`, so it doesn't look animated once it's at 50px left.

Try

`left: "+=50"`

This will cause your div to move 50 pixel to the left everytime it's called, regardless of where it is now

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a ton @NiftyDude. Works great! I had to switch to += for the direction but that was a great answer!

Comment: sure thing, no worries. Edited anyhow :p